# PHP string preg_replace, keep strange letters and numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**I want to keep this letters and numbers in a string**

- åäö and other strange letters
- az and other normal letters
- 123 and other numbers

**I don't want this**

- ##¤&#!.,_- and other strange characters

**Code**

```
$content = preg_replace("???", "", $string);
```

Comment: Please define more clearly what "other strange characters" are. There are hundreds of thousands of possible characters you may be talking about.

Comment: @deceze Yes, disallow all thousands characters that are not numbers or letters.

Comment: Is it UTF-8 encoded input? `$content = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u', "", $string);` might do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Jonny 5 method that consists to write all the characters you need in the character class. You can use the predefined class `\p{Latin}` that contains all latin letters (and accentued letters too):

```
$content = preg_replace('~[^\p{Latin}0-9]+~u', '', $string);
```

If you want all letters or digits "of the world":

```
$content = preg_replace('~\P{Xan}+~u', '', $string);
```

Comment: Maybe offtopic but how can I whitehat some characters, for example space, minus and comma?

Answer (score 4):

Yay for [Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)!

```
$content = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/u", "", $string);
```

- `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter.
- `\p{N}` matches any Unicode digit.
- `[^\p{L}\p{N}]` matches any character that is neither a letter nor a digit.

Comment: +1 Note that this also includes "漢字" for example. Not sure the OP likes that or not.